# No route matches missing :id (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hello this is my controller code for the edit

```
def edit 
  @email = Email.where("organization_id = ? and id = ?", current_users_user.organization_id, params[:id]).first
end
```

my code for the html file

```
<%= form_for @email, url: email_path(@email) do |f| %>
```

and these are my routes...

```
resources :emails, :only => %w(index new create edit update destroy)
```

i am not quite sure what i can possible be doing wrong to receive this message because this is how i am doing it throughout the whole project.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely sure that:

```
@email = Email.where("organization_id = ? and id = ?", current_users_user.organization_id, params[:id]).first
```

returns a record?

To check, you could do:

```
puts "current_users_user.organization_id: #{current_users_user.organization_id}"
puts "params[:id]: #{params[:id]}"
@email = Email.where("organization_id = ? and id = ?", current_users_user.organization_id, params[:id]).first
puts "@email.nil?: #{@email.nil?}"
```

And see what shows up in your console (kludgy, but can work in a pinch).

Also, out of curiosity, why don't you do:

```
@email = Email.find_by(id: params[:id], organization_id: current_users_user.organization_id)
```

Or just:

```
@email = Email.find_by(id: params[:id])
```

It seems like `organization_id` is superfluous, but I may be missing something.

Comment: If `@email` is `nil` then there should a different error message like first argument cannot be `nil`, isn't it?

Comment: Em. Honestly, not 100% sure. However, I *believe* that if `@email` is `nil`, then you'll get the `missing required keys` error. I could test it, but I'd rather wait and see what the OP says.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! @jvillian I fi what you suggested but it hits the error and doesn't print anything in the console. I am assuming it is because it isn't even touching the edit method. Can you think of anything else?

Comment: I added my routes so you guys can use that too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What happened was i wasn't ending my controller class for emails.